# Django 2.0.3 adding data to the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a small problem with adding data to the database in django 2.0.3

I created the following model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserInputSignal(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='signals/', null=True)
```

I tried to solve the problem using this form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserInputSignal

class UserInputSignalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField()
    input_file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserInputSignal
        fields = ('name', 'input_file', )
```

and this view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .forms import UserInputSignalForm

@login_required
def storage(request):

form = UserInputSignalForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        author = request.POST.get(request.user)
        input_file = request.POST.get('input_file')

        return redirect('home')

else:
    form = UserInputSignalForm()

return render(request, 'storage.html', {'form': form})
```

In the template I called, I created the form as follows:

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

I am able to load a page with a form, but it does not post data to the database. I would like to add that I am a novice in django and some mechanisms are just plain understandable for me. Can I ask someone for help with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i worked on your code and it works with me with slight modifications:

**`models.py`**

```
class UserInputSignal(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='signals/', null=True)
objects = models.Manager()

#this returns the name for your modelobject
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**`forms.py`**

```
#excluded the assiging as fields defination is enough in itself

class UserInputSignalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInputSignal
        #this will exclude the formfield it self but the author will be saved as the person who is logged in
        exclude = ["author"]
```

**`Edited - Views.py`**

```
@login_required
def storage(request):
    #authentication for author field using request.user
    insta = UserInputSignal(author=request.user)
    print(request.user)
    form = UserInputSignalForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=insta)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        if form.is_valid():
            signal = form.save(commit=False)           
            signal.save()

            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserInputSignalForm(instance=insta)
    return render(request,  'storage.html', {'form': form})
```

JlucasRs was right to tell you to use `form.save()`, but you needed to assign form to something and need not use model fields here as `forms.py` does that for you.

**`app/Urls.py`** - Just for reference

```
urlpatterns = [
path('home/', home, name='home'),
path('storage/', storage, name='storage'),
]
```

---

**Edit- `Admin.py`**

```
from .models import PostModel, UserInputSignal

class UserInputSignalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('name', 'author', 'input_file' )
admin.site.register(UserInputSignal, UserInputSignalAdmin)
```

**Add this code in `Admin.py` if its not there.**

Comment: I can not check this at the moment, but does the solution you suggest support user authentication when form is filling? I mean adding the author field from the model based on the request.user method or something like that?

Comment: I believe you check this code first and confirm that it works then we'll move ahead with 2 way authentication.

Comment: @MichałKukiełka, i have update the code accordingly to your needs. please refer.

Comment: Ok, the mechanism of adding files proposed by You seems to work, the files appear on the project server. However, when I enter the admin panel of the database, there is no table that matches the UserInputSignal() model.

Comment: Have you registered your **models** in `admin` file?

Comment: I forgot about it completely. I apologize for such basic questions. Your solution works perfectly. : D

Answer (score 2):

Before the redirect, call `form.save()`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but try to put the `form = UserInputSignalForm()` INSIDE the `if request.method == 'POST` and remove the `or None`. It's the only thing I can think it could be affecting it.

Comment: Also, if the form is invalid for some reason, it won't be saved in this case. Try to check what `form.is_valid()` returns True.

Comment: Oi Lucas, please add this kind of extra explanations on the answer itself, it's just a matter of [edit]ing it.